# Serialize List<int> to json using JsonConvert class

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft.dll and this is the scenario,

```
List<int> listNumbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listNumbers);
```

the result is ,

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

But I want the following type of result,

```
 [{"cardvalue":1},{"cardvalue":2},{"cardvalue":3},{"cardvalue":4},{"cardvalue":5}]
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try-

```
    var result = listNumbers.Select(a => new
                {
                    cardvalue = a
                });
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

or serialize result directly -

```
  var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listNumbers.Select(a => new
        {
            cardvalue = a
        }));
```